# How can I get all the possible solutions using NSolve

Tags: equation-solving

How can I get all the possible solutions using `NSolve`. The following equation has eight analytic solutions. These analytic solutions are obtain using "Solve" as shown below. Now, I would like to use "NSolve" to solve the same equation, say for one point `ub = 0.25` and 'k=1', and compare the analytic with the numerical solution. However. "NSolve  gives me only one or two real solutions?!

```
SubPlus[λ] = (-k^2 + Sqrt[ϵ^2 - ub^2])^(1/2); 
SubMinus[λ] = (-k^2 - Sqrt[ϵ^2 - ub^2])^(1/2); 
SubPlus[f] = (I SubPlus[λ] - k)^2/(ϵ - ub); 
SubMinus[f] = (I SubMinus[λ] - k)^2/(ϵ - ub); 
SubPlus[g] = (I SubPlus[λ] + k)^2/(ϵ + ub); 
SubMinus[g] = (I SubMinus[λ] + k)^2/(ϵ + ub);

FullSimplify[
  Solve[
    {Det[
       MatrixForm[
         {{1, 1, -1, -1}, 
          {SubPlus[f], SubMinus[f], -SubPlus[g], -SubMinus[g]}, 
          {SubPlus[λ], SubMinus[λ], SubPlus[λ], SubMinus[λ]}, 
          {SubPlus[λ]*SubPlus[f], SubMinus[λ]*SubMinus[f], 
           SubPlus[λ]*SubPlus[g], SubMinus[λ]*SubMinus[g]}}]]
       == 0}, 
     {ϵ}]]
```

Comment: Please post properly formatted, copy-and-paste-able code rather than this mess (choose Copy as Plain Text). As it is, no one can read and understand what's going on here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem stems from wrapping the matrix given to `Det` with `MatrixForm`. Correcting that gives

```
SubPlus[λ] = (-k^2 + Sqrt[ϵ^2 - ub^2])^(1/2); 
SubMinus[λ] = (-k^2 - Sqrt[ϵ^2 - ub^2])^(1/2); 
SubPlus[f] = (I SubPlus[λ] - k)^2/(ϵ - ub); 
SubMinus[f] = (I SubMinus[λ] - k)^2/(ϵ - ub); 
SubPlus[g] = (I SubPlus[λ] + k)^2/(ϵ + ub); 
SubMinus[g] = (I SubMinus[λ] + k)^2/(ϵ + ub);

FullSimplify[
   Solve[
     Det[
       {{1, 1, -1, -1},
        {SubPlus[f], SubMinus[f], -SubPlus[g], -SubMinus[g]}, 
        {SubPlus[λ], SubMinus[λ], SubPlus[λ], SubMinus[λ]}, 
        {SubPlus[λ]*SubPlus[f], SubMinus[λ]*SubMinus[f], 
         SubPlus[λ]*SubPlus[g], SubMinus[λ]*SubMinus[g]}}] == 0,
     ϵ]]
```

[image: result]